# Robot Framework how to set a variable in an xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, xpath, robotframework, elements

Trying to set a variable in an xpath that I can then replace the text in for a dropdown menu. Not sure if there is a better way to do this I have tried "Replace Variables" also from the String library but also fails. Any help would be appreciated.

Locator:

```
list_item = "xpath=//*[@id='testsection']//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' list-element ')][normalize-space(.) = '${REPLACETHIS}']"
```

Keyword:

```
Generate Locator For
    [Arguments]  ${locator}    ${REPLACETHIS}
    ${new_locator}=   Evaluate    ${locator}.format('${REPLACETHIS}')
    [Return]  ${new_locator}


Test
    ${new_locator}=    Generate Locator For    ${list_item}    default
    log to console  ${new_locator}
```

Result:

```
Evaluating expression 'xpath=//*[@id='test-section']//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' list-element ')][normalize-space(.) = '${REPLACETHIS}'].format('default')' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in variable syntax of Robot Framework to set variables in your XPath expression. Here is an example:

```
${REPLACETHIS}=  Set Variable  default
${list_item}=  Set Variable  xpath=//*[@id='testsection']//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' list-element ')][normalize-space(.) = '${REPLACETHIS}']
```

Then you can use the Replace Variables keyword from the String library to replace the variable in the list_item locator:

```
${new_locator}=  Replace Variables  ${list_item}
```

Alternatively, you can use the Set Test Variable keyword to set the variable and use it in your Generate Locator For keyword:

```
Set Test Variable  ${REPLACETHIS}  default

Generate Locator For
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    ${new_locator}=  Replace Variables  ${locator}
    [Return]  ${new_locator}

${list_item}=  Set Variable  xpath=//*[@id='testsection']//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' list-element ')][normalize-space(.) = '${REPLACETHIS}']
${new_locator}=  Generate Locator For  ${list_item}
```

I hope this helps!